# Why casting to array reference changes value of pointer?

Tags: c++

I have this code snippet:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int first[3][3] = { {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}};
    int (&second)[9] = reinterpret_cast<int(&)[9]>(first);

    for(auto &i: second)
        std::cout << i << " ";

    void * third = (void *) second;

    int (*fourth)[3]   = reinterpret_cast<int(*)[3]>(third);
    int (&fifth)[3][3] = reinterpret_cast<int(&)[3][3]>(third);

    std::cout << first  << " "
              << second << " "
              << third  << " "
              << fourth << " "
              << fifth  << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (auto &x: fourth[i]) {
            std::cout << x << " ";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto &row: fifth) {
        for (auto &x: row) {
            std::cout << x << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Basically I want to cast int[3][3] into void * and then return to int[3][3].

Casting void * to int(*)[3] works fine - all elements shows up. Casting to int(&)[3][3] however does not work and value of fifth differs, first to fourth printed give the same value.

Is there a correct way to cast void* into multidimentional array?

Comment: according to clang we get the warnings: `warning: reinterpret_cast from 'int [3][3]' to 'int (&)[9]' has undefined behavior` and
`warning: reinterpret_cast from 'void *' to 'int (&)[3][3]' has undefined behavior` Your cast to `fourth` is correct - why do you want to have a reference?

Comment: Ok, this sounds reasonable - As in code, I wanted to use c++11 style for over two dimentional array, but casting from void * to int (*)[3] is also ok.

Comment: It’s not relevant to your question, but your *use* of `second` has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `float f;`, `reinterpret_cast<int&>(f)` produces an lvalue of type `int` that refers to `f`.  Similarly,

```
float f,*fp=&f;
do_something(reinterpret_cast<int&>(fp));
```

passes an lvalue referring to `fp`, not `f`.  So in your case, `fifth` refers to `third` itself, not `first` or the fictitious `int[9]` to which `second` refers and whose address is stored in `third`.

The cast you want looks like

```
void *v=&first;
auto &fifth=*reinterpret_cast<int(*)[3][3]>(v);
```